# Error registering on premises node with Azure Automation DSC pull server

Tags: azure, dsc

I just opened an Azure Automation account with a free subscription, in an attempt to experiment with DSC. I've been unable to register an on-premises node with the pull server, any help would be appreciated.

> Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -path C:\Users\eric\DSC\DscMetaConfigs -Verbose

the error I get is:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager -path C:\Users\eric\DSC\DscMetaConfigs -Verbose
>   VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Start-DscConfiguration: SendMetaConfigurationApply" on target
>   "MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager".
>   VERBOSE: Perform operation 'Invoke CimMethod' with following parameters, ''methodName' =
>   SendMetaConfigurationApply,'className' = MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager,'namespaceName' =
>   root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration'.
>   The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is
>   running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the
>   destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the
>   destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".
>       + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80338012
>       + PSComputerName        : EricSamsungLaptop
>   VERBOSE: Operation 'Invoke CimMethod' complete.
>   VERBOSE: Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager finished in 10.097 seconds.

The node I'm attempting to register is a fully up-to-date Windows 10 machine. 
This node's network interface is set to "private", and I even tried temporarily disabling the firewall, but get the same result.

I've generated the .meta.mof with instructions from here: [automation dsc onboarding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding), and also tried using the Get-AzureRmAutomationDscOnboardingMetaconfig cmdlet, but get the same result.

When using a web browser on the node to connect to the registration URL, I get an HTTP 503 error, so the node has connectivity to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable Power Shell Remoting (PS Remoting) to get the Windows 10 node added to Azure Automation. I enabled PS Remoting by running the following cmdlet from an elevated PowerShell session: Enable-PSRemoting.

Once enabled, the Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager cmdlet worked, and the node was added to my instance of Azure Automation.